# How do I convert a list of objects to a list of integers using AutoMapper?

Tags: automapper, flatten

I have a `Student` object:

```cs
public class Student
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

And a `Classroom` object:

```cs
public class Classroom
{
    public List<Student> Students { get; set; }
}
```

I want to use AutoMapper to convert the list of students to a list of student IDs:

```cs
public class ClassroomDTO
{
    public List<int> StudentIds { get; set; }
}
```

How do I configure AutoMapper to do this conversion?

### Answer:

To expand on my question and Jimmy's answer, this is what I ended up doing:

```cs
Mapper.CreateMap<Student, int>().ConvertUsing(x => x.Id);
Mapper.CreateMap<Classroom, ClassroomDTO>()
      .ForMember(x => x.StudentIds, y => y.MapFrom(z => z.Students));
```

AutoMapper was smart enough to do the rest.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You'll need a custom type converter:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<Student, int>().ConvertUsing(src => src.Id);
```

Comment: I don't suppose there's some sort of convention that I can configure so that it always maps collections of reference types to a collection of integers?

Comment: More details here: http://automapper.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Custom%20Type%20Converters&referringTitle=Home